# Possible to fade out div border?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I know you can fade out a `<div>` with jQuery, but I was wondering if it's possible to fade out a border for a `<div>`?

So I've got my `<div>`:

```
<div class="confession" style="border:3px solid #DDD;">
</div>
```

And I'd just like to some how make that border fade out after 5 seconds.

---

**update**

Anyone still wanting to do this can do this with CSS3 transitions.
Just be sure to check it's within your supported browsers capability: http://caniuse.com/#search=transition

*example*

```
div {
    border: 4px solid red;
    -webkit-transition: border-color .25s ease;
       -moz-transition: border-color .25s ease;
        -ms-transition: border-color .25s ease;
         -o-transition: border-color .25s ease;
            transition: border-color .25s ease;
}

div:hover {
    border-color: none;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A real fade out animation would require us to use the alpha channel.
AFAIK jQuery UI's use of `rgba()` is very buggy, so we can use the `step` property to change the opacity of the border like this:

```
setTimeout(function(){

    var div = $('.confession');
    $({alpha:1}).animate({alpha:0}, {
        duration: 1000,
        step: function(){
            div.css('border-color','rgba(0,0,0,'+this.alpha+')');
        }
    });

}, 5000);
```

I used a black border so you can notice the effect, but you can change it to whatever color you want, for example `rgba(221,221,221,'+this.alpha+')');` for `#DDD`

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/victmo/2Xazx/

Cheers!

BTW, no plugins needed for this approach...

Comment: I took a look at the JSFiddle link you provided, however it didn't seem to work :/

Comment: I believe old versions of IE can't handle the rgba property. Which browser did you test it on?

Comment: I just updated the example to fade the border automatically after 5 secs, instead of having to click the square

Comment: Ok, I just tested the example on IE9, FF4 and Chrome13 again and IT WORKS :)

Comment: Sorry for not replying yesterday :) hadn't been online. Thanks for all you've done, it all works! :)

Answer (score 10):

You need to use jQuery UI for that (color animation):

```
$(".confession").animate({
   borderLeftColor: "white",
   borderTopColor: "white",
   borderRightColor: "white",
   borderBottomColor: "white",
}, 3000);
```

(it's not working with borderColor and as for "transparent" it fades to white anyway)

http://jsfiddle.net/Jacek_FH/kxCht/3/

plugin with the similar (same?) capability:

http://docs.jquery.com/Release:jQuery_1.2/Effects#Color_Animations

Comment: And what if his background isn't white, what if it's transparent?

Comment: i'm not sure if jQuery UI handles rgba(), you need to check it for yourself

Comment: Why is jQuery **UI** required?  Can't [jQuery animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) do this alone?

Comment: @Jacek_FH, for some reason I can't get this to work with a delay (the border immediately fades to white/transparent). Do you repro [this](http://jsfiddle.net/kxCht/)? (I'm using Firefox 5.)

Comment: it's not about duration - jQueryUI handles only all 4 border separately

Comment: And even with that, it still can't handle let's say an imaged background. Which will cause it to fade to white while the background is different.

Comment: You guys are missing the point, it's not fading out unless it becomes invisible, which isn't the case in many cases.

Comment: transparent is going to transparent in my local example.

Comment: (On Firefox) For me on your JSFiddle link, it fades out but then changes to white.

Comment: @Richard - yep, that was my explanation to Bobby Borszich - it always fades to white

Answer (score 5):

i like my way more... >.> No plugins needed.

http://jsfiddle.net/MJD5B/2

```
<div class="confession" style="margin:3px;position:relative">
    text
    <div class="fakeBorder"></div>
</div>
```

```
.fakeBorder
{
    position:absolute;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    border:3px solid #DDD;
    margin:-3px;
}
```

Comment: My way too, just add an absolute-positioned element inside and just fade it out - pure jQuery :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid there isn't a clean 100% working way of doing so.

- You could animate the border-width, but that won't be "fading out".
- You could animate the border-color, but that would require an extra library on top of jQuery, plus it will break if you change the background.
- You can fake the border by placing 2 divs on top of each other with a small space, and fade the outer one out, but that isn't really a border and if you'd want something fancy such as a `dashed` or `dotted` border, it won't be that simple.

If you don't plan on having something more fancy than a simple solid border, I suggest using jQuery to generate the 2 divs solution, and then fade out the outer (border) div. Like Joey's answer above me.

Answer (score 1):

The solution below should meet all of your posted criteria:

Wait 5000 ms (5 sec), then animate a fade out of the border that lasts 500 ms (.5 sec).

```
$(".confession").delay(5000).animate({borderWidth: "0"}, 500);
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/ECRLW/

Since the above solution seems to be unable to animate the borderWidth fade with some browsers, the only other way I would know how to accomplish what you want with jQuery would be to use setTimeout():

```
function shrinkBorder(){
    var e = $(".confession");
    var eBorderWidth = e.css("border-width");
    if(eBorderWidth != "0px"){
        e.css("border-width",(eBorderWidth.split("px")[0]-1));
        setTimeout(shrinkBorder, 50);
    }
}

setTimeout(shrinkBorder, 5000);
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/mmfMG/

Comment: Using your JSFiddle, in Safari, the border just pops out... no fading no matter how long I set the duration.

Comment: This is the only one that worked for me, though like Sparky said (however I'm on Firefox) it just disappears, no fading.

Comment: Yeah, to elaborate on that. The border does disappear but it doesn't fade :)

Comment: @Richard & RobB:  New example still not working in Safari... does not fade and does not disappear.