# JQuery animate callback functions with a table

Tags: jquery, html, animation, html-table

I've a rare situation here and I need some ideas, I just prove a lot of combinations but programming is not random!

I've a table with a border = 1px. Also I've a lot of `<td>` and inside of them, one image.
Basically my idea is that when the user clicks on one image (img), all images AND the table border be "fade out", EXCEPT for the clicked image. So I've prove a lot of combinations, and when img disappears, borders not, or nothing disappears, or everything disappears, or the callback doesn't work. My best approach until now is this one:

Supose the following html:

```
<table id="entire">
<tr><td>
<table class="table1" border="1px">
<tr>
<td><img id="ebox"></td>
<td><img id="fbox"></td>
<td><img id="gbox"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td></tr>
</table>
```

And supose the following JQuery:

```
    $("#entire").click(function (event) {

        $('.table1 img').animate({
            opacity: 0.3
            }, 500,
            function() {


        }); //close the animate

$('#' + event.target.id).animate({
            opacity: 0.9
            }, 500,
            function() {


        }); //close the animate

    });  //close the event click
```

I really prove with everything, with ParentNode and call the , and other options like take everything fade out and then fade on.

On the last instance, I know this can be done but I don't know the way. My idea is that the table1 "fades out" EXCEPT the image clicked, and not after, but at the same time.

Any workaround will be treated as solution also, please comment, ask for more information or suggest before downvote. I really search on Google and I also try with "queue off, complete:" but doesn't work.

UPDATE:

last approach:

```
$('.table1 img').not(event.target).animate({alpha: 0.3}, {
        duration: 1000,
    step: function() {
            $('.table1').css('border-color','rgba(0,0,0,'+this.alpha+')');
        }

});
```

Comment: try this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/7031769/889678

Comment: Did you try just `$('.table1 img').not(this).animate({...});`

Comment: yep I tried with not('#' +  event.target.id).animate with similar results

Comment: Did you notice the `this` part ?

Comment: I'll try right now with this, but I don't understand the difference. but let me try!

Comment: ok, this indicate #entire but I just wanna fade out #entire except for the img where I click, for example ebox

Comment: You're not really clicking an image, you're attaching the handler to a container, so `e.target` will be different than `this`, did'nt notice that, and are you sure the event target is'nt the `td`, did you try console logging the event.target ?

Comment: yes, when i click on the image, i put an: alert(event.target.id) so it shows the id of the image. When I change with the <td id="ebox"><img></td>, I've to use the parentNode to get the id because every time the object that fires the event is the image.

Comment: It does seem to work just fine for me [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Vp6ra/) ???

Comment: yeah! ok, but see that the border of the table doesn't "fade out"

Comment: @mgraph please view my update

Comment: Of course it does'nt? Why would the border of the table fadeOut, that would require you to fade out the table which again contains all the images? I see you're now trying some strange stuff with rgba colors and the step function, but that would not be cross browser as not all browsers support rgba, and it will probably give you a shitstorm of other problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery UI allows color animations so with jQuery UI (or an appropriate part of it) installed, try this :

```
var $t = $("#entire table").on('click', 'img', function() {
    $(this).fadeIn(250);
    $t.animate('border-color', '#FFF').find('img').not(this).fadeOut(1000);
});
```

You will only see the border fade effect once unless some other piece of code resets it to its original color.

### EDIT

`.fadeTo()` is probably better than `fadeIn()` / `fadeOut()`; as the faded images remain available to be clicked.

```
var $t = $("#entire table").on('click', 'img', function() {
    $(this).fadeTo(250, 1.0);
    $t.animate('border-color', '#FFF').find('img').not(this).fadeTo(1000, 0.2);
});
```