# Is is possible to change a styled property of a class through a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Firstly, can I refer and change a class through javascript or does the element have to have a specific id?

I have submittable form which is stacked next to a static div of text information. On successful submission, the form fades and displays a confirmation message in the place of the form. However, because this confirmation message is no where near as long (in length/height) as to what the form was, my left hand border on my static element overlaps others.

What I would like to do, is to just remove this border with the fade. In the JS I tried making the correct class a variable and then inline styling it. But it didn't seem to work.

Am I referring to it incorrectly? (it is commented out below)

I'm think that another workaround may be to rename that class to something new after the fade, and then copy everything from the previous without the border in my css. But this seems quite extravagant for something that is probably fairly simple.

**EDIT:** I still am not really understanding it. Since this function is essentially checking for a cookie (if the form has previously been completed), would the change in style be put onto when the cookie is made? Also the style needs to be referred from my style.css file and not inline styling. Just to test, I have set the second style to change the border to another colour rather than disappearing it all together.

**Edit 2**: fixed what I wanted to do will update in the morning.

**HTML**

```
<div class="contactusside">
<p>Some Text</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.contactusside{
  width: 230px;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 0px; 
  margin-right: -10px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-left: 15px;
 border-left: 1px solid #eee;
}

.contactusside2{
  width: 230px;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 0px; 
  margin-right: -10px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-left: 15px;
 border-left: 2px solid #FFF000;
}
.contactusside h2{
  border-bottom: 1px solid #777;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(function() { 
var completed = $.cookie( 'completed' ),
form = $('#contactform'),
msg = $('#contactf'),
sid = $('.contactusside');

if( ( completed != undefined ) && ( completed == 'done' ) ) {
form.hide();
msg.html('<h2 class="green">Success</h2>Thankyou for submitting the form. We will get back to you as soon as possible.' );
sid.toggleClass('contactusside2');
}
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Possible to fade out div border?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7030575/possible-to-fade-out-div-border)

Comment: @JayBlanchard I'm not sure if it's entirely the same thing. I need it to link from my stylesheet rather than inline. Tried to follow over on that question but still hasn't worked out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're already using jQuery, remember that you can select by things other than just by id.

```
$('.class-name') //Selects all items with given class
$('div') //Selects all divs (think of the whole world of CSS style selectors)
```

I'd recommend that if all the items you're talking about have a given class, or can be selected in another way, and if you want to modify them temporarily, then you can do this by toggling another class on them... such as at the beginning and again at the end of the period for which you want the alternate style.

```
$('div.some-class').toggleClass("some-class-alternate-style");
```

The html:

```
<div class="some-class"> This is a box</div>
<div class="some-class"> This is yet another box</div>
```

I'm using div's here, but they could be classes on any element type.

Comment: I think this is kind of what i'm looking for, but i'm still struggling for it to successfully work with the function. see edit.

Answer (score 0):

> Firstly, can I refer and change a class through javascript or does the element have to have a specific id?

Not sure exactly what you mean here, but there are a few ways. Assuming class *foo*,

1. Get a *NodeList* of all *Nodes* with your class

   ```
   var list;
   list = document.getElementsByClassName('foo');
   // or
   list = document.querySelectorAll('.foo'); // etc
   ```
2. Apply a new *style* to all nodes matching your class independently

   ```
   // independentally for each node
   var i;
   for (i = 0; i < list.length; ++i)
       list[i].style.bar = baz;
   ```
3. Apply a new *CSSRule* to all nodes matching your class

   ```
   // all nodes in one rule using a <style>
   var style, sheet;
   style = document.createElement('style'); // or some existing <style>
   document.head.appendChild(style); // don't append if exists already
   sheet = style.sheet; // access sheet from <style>
   sheet.insertRule('.foo { bar: baz; }', Infinity);
   // using index Infinity will always append as the last rule
   ```