# What's the purpose of passing an empty object to jQuery?

Tags: jquery

What does `$({})` in jQuery mean ? I saw this on victmo response on this question : [Possible to fade out div border?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7030575/possible-to-fade-out-div-border)

He used `$({alpha:1}).animate({alpha:0})` how this is affecting the DOM and what happens literally?

Comment: It creates a jQuery object. In that case it will be an empty object. What he was doing was wrong. That code does not point to a DOM object. And you only animate DOM objects.

Comment: @true I wouldn't said he was wrong, it is a trick to animate properties that cannot be animated!

Comment: @Karl-André Gagnon I agree it wasn't politically correct to say he was wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What does $({ }) in jQuery mean ?

It means "pass an empty object to `jQuery` and create a jQuery object from it".

> how this is affecting the DOM and what happens literally?

It doesn't affect the DOM at all, it simply changes the property value of the object `{alpha:1}` over time.

You can use some jQuery methods on plain objects as explained in the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#working-with-plain-objects). Although it seems to be a bit outdated since `animate` is not listed there. But it works indeed:

```
> $({alpha:1}).animate({alpha:0}, {step: function() { console.log(this.alpha); }})
1
0.9965342284774632
0.9870866934849247
0.9730426794137726
0.9524135262330098
0.9242551074907518
0.8926584654403724
0.8563192594626027
...
```