# css element created with jquery fadeIn() after a delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some animation on my page that makes the navbar links fade in and then the logo fades in and finally i use

```
$('.navUl')
.delay(4000)
.queue(function (next) { 
$(this).css('box-shadow', 'inset 0px 0px 1px 1px #FFFFFF'); 
next(); 
});
});
```

to draw a box around everything, but the problem is, the other elements fade in smoothly while this border just kind of appears (literally just being added to the css) and it doesn't look smooth or professional.

I was wondering if there's any way I can make this fade in also, or if there is some other way to make it appear in an appealing manner.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Possible to fade out div border?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7030575/possible-to-fade-out-div-border)

Comment: Show us your full code.